# dojo/request/xhr calling Perl Web Service on different domain -getting scripting errors

Tags: json, perl, dojo, cors

I understand Dojo's XHR mechanism supports CORS but sets the X-Requested-With by default.  I just have to set the headers = {"X-Requested-With":null }

So I am using **dojo/request/xhr** to call a Perl Web Service (Catalyst Framework)

```
 xhr.get(url, {
        handleAs: "json",
        headers: {"X-Requested-With": null}
```

I'm using Fiddler and this is the JSON string:

```
{
   "data" : [
      {
         "structure" : [
            {
               "name" : "State"
            }
            ],
         "dataSource" : [
            {
               "State" : "CA",
               "Id" : 1
            }
           ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Fiddler returns an HTTP Result of 200 but I'm getting an error in dojo.then{}

```
"Unable to load http://Server:3000/state/ status: 0"
```

I also tried using **dojo/request/script** to call a Perl Web Service (Catalyst Framework)

```
script.get(url, {
       jsonp: "callback"
   }).then(...
```

But I get scripting error:

```
JavaScript critical error at line 2, column 11 in http://Server:3000/state/?callback=dojo_request_script_callbacks.dojo_request_script0\n\nSCRIPT1004: Expected ';'
```

It highlights the ":" after "data".  I don't believe this ill-formed json string because my MVC controller method can call the Perl Server using WebClient's DownloadStringTaskAsync and return the value as a ContentString.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using CORS, you have to do more than just setting an `X-Requested-With` header. You also have to make sure the server sends the right headers, it had to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and probably also the `Access-Control-Request-Header` header, for example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Request-Header:  x-requested-with
```

If you're using JSONP, your webservice must support JSONP, which means it's wrapping the entire result in a callback function.